# How do I show more surrounding code in byebug?

Tags: ruby, byebug

By default byebug shows 10 lines, e.g. lines `[40, 49]`
How can I easily see some more surrounding code? For example lines 30-60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`set listsize`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md#examining-program-source-files-list).

P.S. never used byebug, just a quick sight on the gem's Readme.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is

```
l 30-60
```

Thanx to Andrey Deineko, never would find readme with documentation about asked method

Comment: This is the answer anyone would look for